# Error with ORDER BY clause using UNION in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-order-by, union

I have the following query in MySQL:

```
(SELECT ue.id, ue.userid, ue.status, ue.timestart, ue.timeend, e.courseid,
        e.id AS enrolid, ra.roleid
 FROM user_enrolments ue
 JOIN enrol e ON e.id = ue.enrolid
 JOIN course c ON c.id = e.courseid
 JOIN user u ON u.id = ue.userid
 JOIN context ct ON ct.instanceid = c.id
 LEFT JOIN role_assignments ra ON ra.userid = u.id AND 
                               ra.contextid = ct.id AND
                               ra.itemid = e.id
 WHERE e.customint1 = 1 AND u.deleted = 0 AND 
       ct.contextlevel = 50 AND (ue.status = 0 OR ue.status = 1)) 

UNION

(SELECT de.enrolid AS id, de.userid, de.status, de.date_ini, de.date_fin, 
        de.courseid, de.enrolid, de.roleid
 FROM deleted_enrols de
 JOIN user u ON u.id = de.userid
 WHERE userid = ANY (SELECT userid FROM local_users WHERE clientid = 1))

ORDER BY u.firstname, u.lastname, c.fullname LIMIT 0, 100
```

If I delete ORBER BY and LIMIT, this query works fine... but the ORDER BY clause gives an error:

```
Table 'u' from one of the SELECTs cannot be used in global ORDER clause
```

If I delete the parentheses of both SELECT querys, the error is different:

```
Table 'u' from one of the SELECTs cannot be used in field list
```

I have also tried with UNION ALL, but it does not work either.

Any suggestion or clue? Thanks in advance for your time...

Comment: The problem is with the scope of the aliases. 'U' doesn't exist where you are trying to use it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The results of your `UNION` do not include any fields from table 'u', so those results cannot be sorted by table 'u' fields.

You could perhaps perform the UNION and then re-join the results to table 'u', and then use that to sort the results by table 'u' fields. A similar issue exists for sorting on 
`course.fullname`, so that would need to be joined back in, too.

```
SELECT x.id, x.userid, x.status, x.timestart, x.timeend, x.courseid, x.enrolid, x.roleid
FROM ((SELECT ue.id, ue.userid, ue.status, ue.timestart, ue.timeend, e.courseid,
        e.id AS enrolid, ra.roleid
       FROM user_enrolments ue
         JOIN enrol e ON e.id = ue.enrolid
         JOIN course c ON c.id = e.courseid
         JOIN user u ON u.id = ue.userid
         JOIN context ct ON ct.instanceid = c.id
         LEFT JOIN role_assignments ra ON ra.userid = u.id 
           AND ra.contextid = ct.id 
           AND ra.itemid = e.id
       WHERE e.customint1 = 1 AND u.deleted = 0 
           AND ct.contextlevel = 50 AND (ue.status = 0 OR ue.status = 1)) 
       UNION
       (SELECT de.enrolid AS id, de.userid, de.status, de.date_ini, de.date_fin, 
        de.courseid, de.enrolid, de.roleid
        FROM deleted_enrols de
          JOIN user u ON u.id = de.userid
         WHERE userid = ANY (SELECT userid FROM local_users WHERE clientid = 1))
) x
  JOIN user z ON z.id = x.userid
  JOIN course d ON d.id = x.courseid
ORDER BY z.firstname, z.lastname, d.fullname LIMIT 0, 100
```

Comment: Thanks a lot... I've added 'x.id' in the first select because I got a message warning that column 'id' was ambiguous and now it works fine...

Comment: Of course. Sorry I didn’t catch that while putting together my answer. I will adjust it.

Comment: I realized that I added that `id` column twice, and it should only be added once.  I've updated my answer to remove the second `id` and to add table aliases to all the fields in the first `SELECT`.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you want to sort the whole lot, try parentheses round the whole query with the ORDER BY done afterwards:

```
select id, userid, status, timestart, timeend, courseid, enrolid, roleid from
((SELECT ue.id, ue.userid, ue.status, ue.timestart, ue.timeend, e.courseid,
        e.id AS enrolid, ra.roleid, u.firstname, u.lastname, c.fullname
 FROM user_enrolments ue
 JOIN enrol e ON e.id = ue.enrolid
 JOIN course c ON c.id = e.courseid
 JOIN user u ON u.id = ue.userid
 JOIN context ct ON ct.instanceid = c.id
 LEFT JOIN role_assignments ra ON ra.userid = u.id AND 
                               ra.contextid = ct.id AND
                               ra.itemid = e.id
 WHERE e.customint1 = 1 AND u.deleted = 0 AND 
       ct.contextlevel = 50 AND (ue.status = 0 OR ue.status = 1)) 

UNION

(SELECT de.enrolid AS id, de.userid, de.status, de.date_ini, de.date_fin, 
        de.courseid, de.enrolid, de.roleid, u.firstname, u.lastname, ' ' as fullname
 FROM deleted_enrols de
 JOIN user u ON u.id = de.userid
 WHERE userid = ANY (SELECT userid FROM local_users WHERE clientid = 1))) s1

ORDER BY firstname, lastname, fullname LIMIT 0, 100
```

(obviously fullname in the second SELECT statement would be populated however seems sensible)

Answer (score 2):

You need to include the data to be ordered by in the selects of the unioned queries; an ORDER BY following a UNION is handled *as if* it were `SELECT * FROM (unions) ORDER BY ...` so anything not coming out of the union cannot be used for ordering.

Ironically, a query similar to that is the key to getting what you want though, with something like

```
SELECT x, y, z
FROM (
SELECT x, y, z, somethingIdontactuallywant
FROM blah
UNION
SELECT a, b, c, somethingIdontactuallywant
FROM blah2
) AS u
ORDER BY u.somethingIdontactuallywant
```

Answer (score 1):

As mysql documentation on [union](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/union.html) says:

> This kind of ORDER BY cannot use column references that include a
>   table name (that is, names in tbl_name.col_name format). Instead,
>   provide a column alias in the first SELECT statement and refer to the
>   alias in the ORDER BY. (Alternatively, refer to the column in the
>   ORDER BY using its column position. However, use of column positions
>   is deprecated.)
>
> Also, if a column to be sorted is aliased, the ORDER BY clause must
>   refer to the alias, not the column name.

So, do not refer to any table names and use columns that are actually in the resultset of the union.